# I'm unable to install setuptools using commandline in ubuntu. I've used "pip install setuptools" but its showing an error:

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm unable to install setuptools using commandline in ubuntu. I've used "pip install setuptools" but its showing an error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/logan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/logan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
prefix=options.prefix_path,
File "/home/logan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
**kwargs
File "/home/logan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
File "/home/logan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
isolated=self.isolated,
File "/home/logan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
File "/home/logan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 323, in clobber
shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 83, in copyfile
with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appdirs.py'
```

help me guyz!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running as root? Run as root or put in your own area with the --user flag.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have permissions to alter a file that you need to alter.

```
Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/appdirs.py'
```

Run it again as root, or run it with sudo in front of it. Either that or try to grant permissions to the folder.

```
su root
pip install setuptools
```

or

```
sudo pip install setuptools
```

or

```
chmod -R +w /usr/local/lib/python2.7;
pip install setuptools
```

Or install locally. You can do that with the --user flag or with virtualenv if you have that installed.

```
pip install --user setuptools
```

or

```
virtualenv <envdir>
source <envdir>/activate
pip install setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line indicates that you don't have sufficient rights to install into /usr/lib.

Maybe you need to have at least superuser rights to do so but that depends on your OS.

A quick solution would be to try and run the command with `sudo`